# call java functions in pthread with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, pthreads

I want to call a java method inside a pthread.

the C++ method start like this :

```
char* FileLoader::getStringFromFile(char* a_filename)
{
   JNIEnv *env;
   g_jvm->AttachCurrentThread (&env, NULL);
   jclass cls = env->FindClass(JAVA_FILE_LOADER_CLASS);
   ...
```

g_jvm points to the JavaVM object. it is set when the app start in the JNI_OnLoad() method.

When "FindClass" is called, it throws a "noClassDefFoundError" but if I call this method in the main thread, it works as expected.

Have I forgotten something ?

Comment: Sounds funky. Does AttachCurrentThread() return a zero? Have you tried other classes (something vanilla like `java.lang.String`)?

Comment: How is JAVA_FILE_LOADER_CLASS defined? is it perhaps defined in another file?

Comment: AttachCurrentThread() return zero. Yes I tried other classes and the same method called in the main thread works. JAVA_FILE_LOADER_CLASS is a constant for my java class (com/Framework/IO/FileLoader)

Comment: You should check what the class loader is in the working case.  You may need to explicitly provide it to the native thread if there is a context class loader or other custom class loader.

Comment: I try to load java.lang.string and it throws the same exception

Comment: You might try caching the class and method IDs in the main thread and using them in the non-main thread.  And make sure you don't have typos in your class lookup, the format is "java/lang/String".

Comment: [@Klem](http://stackoverflow.com/users/475625/klem): I tried the scenario you describe on 2.3 and 4.1 emulators, and both produce correct results.

Comment: I made a try by passing my class and method id static (it was set just once in the main thread) and I got another error : JNI WARNING: jclass is an invalid local reference (0x1e000005)

Comment: Indeed, I miswrite the string class name. With "java/lang/String" the class is well loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solve the problem with the advice of technomage :

In my JNI_OnLoad() method :

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void * reserved)
{
    JNITools::g_jvm = vm;

    JNIEnv *env;
    g_jvm->AttachCurrentThread (&env, NULL);jclass tmpClass = env->FindClass("com/Framework/IO/CFileLoader");
    g_fileLoaderClass = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(tmpClass);
    ...
```

My first test has failed because I forgot to call NewGlobalRef().

This [doc](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html) helped me to understand why it is needed.